# PHP echoing setTimeout() to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an ajax application using PHP. It loads videos, and ajax needs to load another video after a variable number of seconds it gets from the database. I am trying to echo a setTimeout along with the video, like so, with loadContent being the function that loads videos.

```
            echo '<iframe id="youtubeFrame" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/
            '.$row['youtube'].'
            ?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

            $refreshTimer = $row['end'] - $time;
            $refreshTimer = $refreshTimer * 1000;
            echo $refreshTimer;
            echo '<script>
            setTimeout(loadContent, '.$refreshTimer.');
            </script>';
```

The video loads, the variable refreshTimer is the right amount of seconds, but it won't run the setTimeout.

How do I get the page to refresh when my database tells it to?

UPDATE: I've been told the variable needs to be turned into an Int, but that can't be the case, because when there is no video, this code runs.

```
        echo '<h1>Upload content to start the show</h1>';

            echo '<script>
            setTimeout(loadContent, 4000);
            </script>';
```

This doesn't involve any php variables, it is a direct number, and this doesn't work as well. I'm curious on how to pass data to ajax through the success, but I'm having trouble looking up relevant information online when searching.

Comment: Why not setting the timeout event on AJAX success ?

Comment: What does `echo $refreshTimer` show ? And does `loadContent` get called at least once? Wondering if your confusing this with `setInterval`.

Comment: $refreshTimer shows the amount I want it to, and loadContent is getting it's initial call. As to Syed Quaib, that's a great point. I haven't had to use success yet. How do I pass data to it?

Comment: You still ain't told me what `$refreshTimer` holds. And is it `string` or `int` data type? If you don't convert it to a number it won't work. My guess is javascript will intepret the php var as a string. So try to use `parseInt`

Comment: Ah, I think you're right Dave. Is one method preferable over the other?

Comment: @Goose parseInt should be sufficient, but i wonder if there will be something else also causing the problem besides data type. But if it solved the problem please tick the answer :)

Comment: Your update makes no sense, in that example you are giving it a number. In your PHP example you giving the value like this:
`setTimeout(loadContent, '4000');` which is a string, notice the `'`. So that update version is the right datatype.

Comment: I understand, and yet it would seem to both of us that the code in the update should set a Timeout successfully, but it's not, so I'm guessing I have a problem unrelated to the variable on top of any string/Int problems I have.

Comment: @Goose how big is the number for the PHP variable?

Comment: 6 digits. It's miliseconds to wait. It adds up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess based on your information provided is the PHP variable will be considered a `string` and not an `integer`.

So convert it like this:

```
echo '<script>
 setTimeout(function(){loadContent();}, parseInt('.$refreshTimer.'));
</script>';
```

**Side note** it would be wise to learn how to seperate PHP and JS (server side and client side) using ajax in the future :)

Comment: You didn't show the parseInt. Also, can I run a javascript function on a php variable. I thought parseInt was suppose to be used with javascript functions.

Comment: @Goose I have edited it in now. PHP is a totally different language to JS, theres no way JS will know if the variable is holding a number or a string. It will usually default to string until you convert it to integer. And setTimeout expects a number or it won't work.

Comment: Ah, this won't work. I updated my question to show another crucial hint.

Comment: @Goose i don't see any thing different?

Comment: @Goose try my updated version which holds an unnamed function. It might solve it - not sure why it would if the parseInt does not.

Comment: No success. Still refuses to refresh. Can I use the success in ajax to execute the setTimeout()?